# how to create a image slideshow for blackberry?

Tags: user-interface, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

what i am trying to do is that on click of a button in screen1, i try push the screen2 repeatedly with different images and different Transition Context.

the code is as follows

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
{
        if(field==slideButton)
        {       
            for(int i=0;i<bitmaps.length;i++)
            {



                slideScreen = new SliderScreen(bitmaps[i]);

                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(slideScreen);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(slideScreen);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that nothing appears.Is there any other way to achieve this..

Answer (score 0):

Fixed version of your initial idea:

```
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
    if (field==slideButton) {

        final UiApplication app = UiApplication.getUiApplication();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < bitmaps.length; i++) {
                    final SliderScreen slideScreen = 
                        new SliderScreen(bitmaps[i]);

                    app.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            app.pushScreen(slideScreen);
                        }
                    });

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    app.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            app.popScreen(slideScreen);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Your code did not work because the UI thread was sleeping between push and pop, so it has no time/chance to start drawing the screen. Note I moved the entire action into a separate thread. So now the main UI thread has free time to actually make drawing.

Comment: @Manish: Any success with this?